# Ruby on Rails - Undefined Method in a max_by model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to find something similar on Stack but with no luck.

I want to get the max_by of relevance to only get 1 result.
I stored values in a `tmp` variable and the trace backlog returns :

```
 #<Object:0x007f89e852e1e8>
 #<Object:0x007f89e852e030>
 #<Object:0x007f89e852d6f8>
 #<Object:0x007f89e852d400>
 #<Object:0x007f89e852d018>
 #<Object:0x007f89e852cde8>
 #<Object:0x007f89e852cb68>
```

So, I have 7 objects returned in `tmp`variable but when I try to do a max_by :

```
def update
  if params[:user_id].blank? 
    render json: "No user", status: 500
  else
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    tmp = user.family.map(&:objects)
    object1=tmp.max_by(&:relevance)
    @hierarchy.update_column("top_hierarchy", object1.keyword)
    render json: @hierarchy, status: 200
  end
end
```

as mentionned I also tried to isolate each object within a loop (and got same error ) :

```
tmp.each do |my_object|
  puts my_object.relevance
end
```

and the tracelog :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `relevance' for #<Object::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f89ed968ab0>):
```

**Here are some informations about the Models**

`Object` is an independant model, defined with attributes as below. 
`Family` belongs to user and possesses `family_objects` that is a mapping table  with `Object` and `Family`.

Models :

```
#FamilyObject attributes
FamilyObject(id: integer, family_id: 204, object_id: 303: integer)

#Family model
belongs_to :user
has_many :family_objects, class_name: 'Family::FamilyObject', dependent: :destroy
has_many :objects, through: :family_objects
```

---

```
#Object attributes
Object(id: integer, relevance: integer, keyword: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, verified: boolean)

#Object Model
has_many :family_objects, class_name: 'Family::FamilyObject', dependent: :destroy
has_many :families, through: :family_objects
```

It's probably pretty obvious, but I cant' figure it out !

Comment: Can you post the code used to get `tmp`

Comment: I updated my code ( note : it is called in a create method )

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.relevance` on a collection rather than a single object. Is it possible that there are 2 objects with the same relevance so it is returning a collection rather than a single object?

Comment: I tried to get one by one with a .each loop. and inside the loop I did a `puts my_object.relevance` but it outputs the same error

Answer (score 0):

According to APIDock,

> Association proxies in Active Record are middlemen between the object
>   that holds the association, known as the @owner, and the actual
>   associated object, known as the @target. The kind of association any
>   proxy is about is available in @reflection. That’s an instance of the
>   class ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection.

So what you are doing is calling the `relevance` method on the association object, and not the object itself.

You can try

```
object1 = tmp.max_by { |obj| obj.relevance }
```

This should call the `relevance` method on each of the object.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for this input. I tried it but sadly got always the same error. Also I don't really understand the reflection concept that ActiveRecord adds. As  the backend returns the final object as the one that is targeted, why should ruby go through this syntax ?

Comment: can you show us the relationship between `user` and `object`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer : I added the models concerned in the description. In fact I use a mapping table between User, another model and the Object model. Could the mapping be the cause of the issue ?